# How to create landing pages and Main Menu based on taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 7

I'm trying to build a website for a non-profit which has multiple locations (~6) besides the headquarters.

The frontpage needs to be generic for the whole organization and will contain content from all locations.

However, each location needs have its own page ( not only the content part but also the main menu and the header etc.) and all the content(nodes etc.) associated with this location should use the same page template associated with this location. So I've created a taxonomy term for each location and tried to use template suggestions based on the term but it didn't work.

So far I was successful creating a panel page with its own path (such as website.org/headquarters) for each location and show content only for that location by filtering via the taxonomy term but no luck for having custom main menu or custom node pages for the location.

Is there something trivial that I'm missing or is there no easy solution for this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the perfect use case for [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og)

> Enable users to create and manage their own 'groups'. Each group can
>   have subscribers, and maintains a group home page where subscribers
>   communicate amongst themselves.
>
> They do so by posting the usual node types: blog, story, page, etc. A
>   block is shown on the group home page which facilitates these posts.
>   The block also provides summary information about the group.

There is also a kick-ass set of tutorial videos from BuildAModule [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej4yT2Z8fac&feature=list_other&playnext=1&list=SPF3F33F9F7DAEB676) that should help you set it up.